# HTML5 live broadcasting

Tags: flash, html5, rtmp

Adobe Flash uses Adobe Flash Player, RTMP protocol, Flash Media Server and Flash Media Live Encoder to make live broadcasting possible..

What protocol and software corresponds  to HTML video/audio ?

What can replace  RTMP protocol, Flash Media Server and Flash Media Live Encoder?

Is it possible with HTML5?

Comment: Related StackOverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735933/streaming-via-rtsp-or-rtp-in-html5

Answer (score 3):

Wowza is currently working on their [Media Server](http://www.wowza.com/), which will support HTML5. [You can view it here](http://www.wowza.com/_demo/webm/html5.html), it's playing a movie last I checked.

It uses [WebM,](http://www.webmproject.org/) which is a project *dedicated to developing a high-quality, open video format for the web that is freely available to everyone.* It's based on a [Matroska container.](http://corecodec.com/products/matroska) It's currently in use by YouTube to play HTML5 video.

> The source of this stream is a WebM file that is streamed as a live
>   stream using the Wowza server-side publishing API.

According to the tag note:

> Note: A browser that supports HTML5, WebM, VP8 and Ogg Vorbis is
>   required. Works with the following browsers:

So these appear to be the requirements to get a web browser to live stream.

Answer (score 3):

[HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) is an extension of HTML4, and as such works using any tcp/ip port as specified in the src parameter of the [video tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080122/#video). It is handled directly by the browser, not using any plugin such as Flash, and is therefore the only existing streaming solution for mobile devices.

[HTML5 video](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video) is protocol agnostic - the protocol is implied by the source URL, as for example in :

```
<video src="rtp://myserver.com/path/to/stream">
    Your browser does not support the VIDEO tag and/or RTP streams.
</video>
```

or maybe :

```
<video src="http://myserver.com:1935/path/to/stream/myPlaylist.m3u8">
    Your browser does not support the VIDEO tag and/or RTP streams.
</video>
```

This all depends on the browser's support for the protocol that is used.
Simply streaming a video file is normally always supported, but more complicated cases
as above may require the use of a plugin when the browser lacks the required support.

HTML5 players can be built using as tools only HTML, CSS and Javascript.

An example is [VideoJS](http://videojs.com/), a 
free & open source lightweight player that is 100% skinnable using CSS, whose website also contains lots of useful information about HTML5 video.

Much more information is available around the Kaltura project, which is best accessed
starting with [html5video](http://html5video.org/) - A Kaltura community site. This site also contains
an [HTML5 Player Comparison](http://html5video.org/wiki/Player_Comparison) and the article [Getting Started - Navigating HTML5](http://html5video.org/wiki/Getting_Started_-_Navigating_HTML5)

To publish an existing video file on HTML5, one can use the free [Html5 Video Creator](http://html5video-tag.com/html5-video-tag-google-chrome.html) which creates the HTML5 code for you.